# Selenium and Python click button with text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have tried so many ways and I cannot for the life of me click this button!

This is my current attempt. Can someone help point out what i'm missing?

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="btn regular-button main-button regular-main-button submit progress-state still"]').click()
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn regular-button main-button regular-main-button submit progress-state still" onclick="javascript: this.form.submit();">
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The xpath in your `driver.find_element()` seems correct when I loaded the html with `lxml.html.fromstring()` and searched with `etree.xpath()`. Without seeing the exact source html I think the odds of success would be quite low.

Comment: Test your locator on the page itself to see if it returns more than one element... that may be the issue. You can use `$$()` to test CSS selectors and `$x()` to test XPaths, e.g. for this button try `$$("button.submit")`. If it returns only 1 element then you are good to go. If it returns more than one element, you will have to craft a more specific locator. If you provide a link to the page, we can help you.

Comment: Have you tried adding the perform call? Instead of `.click()`, try `.click().perform()`

Comment: I just added an image of the html code for this. the click().perform() didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to .submit or click with JavaScript executer.

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn regular-button main-button regular-main-button submit progress-state still")
    
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: No luck on this one either, thank you for trying though!

Answer (score 0):

Following up, I found that the submit function worked instead of click.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="btn regular-button main-button regular-main-button submit progress-state still"]').submit()
```